# DPKG error message with libsane while installing WineHQ-stable

Tags: wine, dpkg

With a fresh copy of 17.10 ubuntu installed.  I have found a repeatable error which I believe is messing up my wine installation permanently.  After the error I simply format the system and retry another time.  The error message is encountered when installing winehq.  Both stable and staging versions run into the exact same problem.

I cannot find an answer on the internet.  Please help if you can.

```
Selecting previously unselected package libtxc-dxtn-s2tc:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../150-libtxc-dxtn-s2tc_1.0+git20151227-2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libtxc-dxtn-s2tc:i386 (1.0+git20151227-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-mh7wRK/137-libsane1_1.0.27-1~experimental2ubuntu1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 4):

I met the same problem and solve it.
This is caused by [a bug in `sane-backends`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1725928).

First, remove Wine, then execute:

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install libsane1:i386
```

and then install Wine again.

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt purge winehq-stable wine-mono wine-gecko winetricks
```

Basically ppa remove and purge your current wine installation using above commands, then :

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt update
```

Now to install winehq-stable

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Above is the the current installation procedure as the launchpad Wine ppa is DEPRECATED, see link : https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa for details.

EDIT : If you are still facing a problem with libsane package, report a bug to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends there is a chance that this bug may have been already reported and fixed.

Comment: I have tried those exact steps to install wine on a fresh Ubuntu...  several times.  I always get the error message I posted.

Comment: @Daniel try : " sudo apt-get install wine-staging winehq-staging winetricks "                    If that fails try " sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel "

Comment: @Daniel Also read my answer for edit at end.

Comment: himanshuxd, Had a similar issue while installing winehq-staging. My system automatically reported it as a bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1795330). Your solution worked great. No errors reported. Thank you.

Comment: @hienz1 glad I could be of help.

Answer (score -2):

in synaptic search for "libsane" and install all the extras, devs etc. worked for me on ubuntu studio 17.10

Comment: I don't think that's going to solve package dependency issues with packages stemming from some PPA.